# Synchronization xml file across multiple servers(machine)

Tags: c#, xml, share, synchronized

In our application there are multiple client applications.

One client application is setup on a separate server(machine).

There is a module named as reconciliation, preferences(setting) of this module are saved in xml file on hard disk of each serer.

My requirement is that i want to share preferences of one server to another server for view purpose only. 
i.e. user u1 on server A can view preferences of server B but can't edit these preferences.

The main thing is that preferences should be real time synchronized with the server.
i.e. user u1 on server A is viewing the preferences and at that time a user on server B changes the preferences then preferences should be updated on server A for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some sort of pub/sub system that each application is listening to. When a preference is saved it will publish a message with information about whose preferences have changed. Each application is also subscribed to the system and will receive the message saying something has changed.  You can either publish the preferences with the message of store them somewhere centrally and have each application go and retrieve them

Another option is to store the preferences in a shared folder (maybe one file user preference) and have your applicaton watch that folder for changes. When the user file changes you can reload the file.

If you choose to save the preferences in the database then you'll need to poll the database from time to time in order to see if anything has changed. You can avoid the polling if you go with a pub/sub system, but if you don't you'll need to think about how often you poll the database and how it will scale when you take into account the number of instances of your application are running and how often you check the database.

Comment: Pub sub could be a difficult approach as publishing to different machine could be a difficult task. Second approach means a lot to share the preferences using shared folder. Can you guide me that should i save these preferences in database or not. I think preferences can be synchronized using database.

Comment: @NarendraJangir - I've added some more info to the answer

Comment: File in shared folder will work fine for me, as we can apply locking mechanism on files.